# How do I include "ibmiot" input node to my local installation of Node-RED

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I want to include the "ibmiot" Input node into my local installation of Node-RED ?

Can I do it ? and if so - how ?

The Node-RED flow editor that shows up when I start the Bluemix IoT Starter, shows the node that exactly - fits into what I want to do.

It has the API Keys, device Type, ID and so on as seen below. I'm trying to add this to my local install of Node-RED.

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Below - I want to add the same node ( or import ) into my Laptop where I have the Node-RED installed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iotapp nodes are provided by the `node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp` module - http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-scx-ibmiotapp

Comment: Thanks for replying - I will check it out. Your response is very much appreciated. Shashi